# Getting the index of an array

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of names

`names = c('Alex','Brad', 'Camilla')`

If I had an array like

`norder = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2)`

Then I could use `norder` to access `names` by doing

```
names[norder]

>>> c('Alex', 'Brad', 'Camilla', 'Brad', 'Alex', 'Brad', 'Alex',
       'Camilla', 'Brad', 'Brad')
```

How do I go in the reverse?  Given

`order= c('Alex', 'Brad', 'Camilla', 'Brad', 'Alex', 'Brad', 'Alex',
           'Camilla', 'Brad', 'Brad')`

and `names`, how do I return something that looks like `norder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
match(order, names)
# [1] 1 2 3 2 1 2 1 3 2 2
```